# use systemSound from SystemSoundID for UNNotificationSound

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unusernotificationcenter, unnotificationrequest

I am trying to add a sound to my UNNotification.  Instead of my own custom sound or the default sound, I would like to use one of the iOS SystemSounds in AVFoundation.  I can get the sound by:

```
import AVFoundation
...
let systemSoundID: SystemSoundID = 1016
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(systemSoundID)
```

How can I add this sound to my notification?